# K2 Studio workflow

Tags: k2

I am now making a Form that can be `Approve` or `Reject` by approver.
My Forms, Views, SmartObjects works well.

I want to add a withdraw function in `Workflow`.

Things i want to do : If requester withdraw the form, workflow should be terminated. (It means that the worklist of the current item should be disappear from the approver's worklist.)

I don't want to requester having the worklist item because it is no sense if they don't withdraw the form.

Any ideas for the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can withdraw the worklist item using the release task in the worklist.
The Release option allows a manager to release an Open worklist item from the current user's worklist so that it becomes Available to other destination users setup by the Destination Rule. Only Work Items with Open status can be released.
Hope this will be helpful for you